# iOS 6 facebook Auth Application status

Tags: facebook, authentication

I'm doing Facebook auth with SDK 3.1 on iOS6.
I have an existing app that was using old FB SDK.

Apparently, I've implemented:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session,
       FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
}];
```

but initially I've got "error 2" with FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed after the first logging attempt.

No auth dialog was provided. App initially became inactive in iOS-Settings -> Facebook.

I've tried several solutions, but the setting is disabled by default on any new device with configured Facebook account.

Please, help :)

Comment: Can you try passing 'nil' for permissions instead of an actual permissions array?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with Facebook SDK 3.5.1? I have developed a plugin for game developers using the same SDK and none of my plugin user facing this problem.